# Video Game Trailer Critique?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, video-games, feedback

Hey guys. I just asked a question the other day (maybe yesterday) about how I can practice sound design. I got some really good feedback and saw a few people that had posted their videos to be reviewed on here so I thought I would do the same.

This is a game called The Secret World that I found on youtube.

Let me know what you think I could do better or focus on more. After listening to it in the studio I noticed the cry of the baby could have come down a bit and the headphones could been a bit more 'muffled.'

[vimeo]12796980[/vimeo]

Give me your thoughts.

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 2):

A tiny bit of Foley would certainly add character to the fight but otherwise it is GOOD. That's what I thought when I watched it :)

Can I ask how you get access to a studio? Are you already a sound guy? Are you training in some school? I'm looking for this kind of opportunities myself...

Comment: I attended Recording Workshop in Chillicothe, Ohio for a couple of certifications in this field. I'm interning at a studio right now and learning/teaching myself as much as possible. I'm more of a music based engineer/musician but I think this is the area I really want to strive in to be as good as possible. If you're looking for opportunities I would suggest finding an internship/job at a studio to work in and do as many things on the side as you can even if they are for free. 

Comment: Thanks JM, I'm already working on projects at the moment even though I never really designed sound, I've mostly done editing. I'm moving back to my parents' in two weeks where I'll set up a small home studio and hopefully get started with the real thing! I'm actually gonna create a thread about the best ways to get started :)

Answer (score 2):

First... You found an AWESOME trailer. Great find, man. I'll share the same advice I received for my sound design project. I think you need a bigger contrast between the normal everyday world and the frightening event that occurs. The sound for when the monster appears doesnt necessarily have to be loud for the sake of being loud but it should be jarring nonetheless. I was more affected by the visual than by the sound in this take.  Perhaps, there's some wicked breathing going on or an uncomfortable whine that occurs when we see the bad guy suddenly appear. When she does her magic thing, that should be big as well.

In order to setup the contrast, I think your sound design for the normal everyday section at the start of the trailer could benefit from more layers of sound design. Something that really lulls the viewer into thinking that this is just a simple, normal, everyday world. Good job with the music on the headphones. I think you should definitely build on this trailer! I would definitely like to see your progress on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll work on those areas of it and see how it turns out.

By the way, I like what you had on the FEAR 3 trailer. I can't wait to hear what it sounds like when you're done!

Answer (score 1):

It works very well. Nicely done! One thing though (added to the other feedback), after the monster gets blasted out the window, which sounds awesome, I would emphasize the debris. I would also work on the introduction of the monster sound, maybe a nice deep growl and breath. I'm listening on really bad headphones and in a coffee shop, so as a mix, the beginning is very soft in relation to the rest, which is very loud. Have you tried adding a little compression on the master?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have thought of emphasizing the debris. I did compress the master. I think it was around 3.9dB's GR. Any suggestions when it comes to compressing the master?

Comment: @JM it's totally up to you. The debris emphasis was just my gut instinct talking. I don't think I can give you a hard and fast rule for compression, check out some mastering presets on your compressor and play from there. I'm sure though, if I had listened on good speakers/headphones it would have been better. The compression helps the softer sounds push through. 

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome.  I agree with what everyone else has said... make the monster and the combat bigger.  Or, conversely, make it closer to strict realism (there's not enough of that in video games, IMO).

I feel like the monster needs something moist in his sounds, too.

Comment: Thanks and I agree completely abut the realism. I did have a little slimy effect going on once they meet face to face, so maybe I could incorporate that idea into multiple elements of the monster.

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned this same trailer not too long ago ([an interesting comparison](https://vimeo.com/10560937)). Unlike mine, I like that yours has a good dynamic range to it. Everyone has brought up some great ideas already. I would say to put foley to the whole thing. At the very least put in her footsteps, even though we only see her take a couple. It makes it way more cinematic. Keep up the great work.

Comment: I really liked your redesign, especially hearing the other apartments' bass coming through the walls -- I wish that would have stayed in longer.  Also, maybe I'm totally out of it, today, but I didn't catch your use of the Wilhelm Scream... so, if it's in there, good job avoiding one of my pet peeves. 

Comment: Glad you liked it. I put the Wilhelm in for the monster vocals when it gets blasted out the window. It's pitched and tweaked, but I still have a bit of the original there as a sweetener. I didn't want to blatantly rip it off, but I still wanted to keep the gag running.